# help with exercise 4.6 in humphreys lie algebras book

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

$(\delta-(a+b).1)^n(xy)= \sum_{i=0}^n {{n}\choose{i}}(\delta-a.1)^{n-i}(x)\dot(\delta-b.1)^{i}(y)$

I need to prove this formula, where $\delta$ is a derivation, $a$ and $b$ are in a field $F$ and $x$,$y$ are elements of a finite dimentional $F$-algebra.

I tried doing it by induction, I proved the cases $N=0,1$ but I got stuck doing the inductuive step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you've checked that
$$
(\delta-(a+b).1)(xy)=(\delta-a.1)(x)y+x(\delta-b.1)(y).
$$
For the inductive step,
\begin{align}
(\delta-(a+b).1)^n(xy)=&(\delta-(a+b).1)^{n-1}((\delta-a.1)(x)y+x(\delta-b.1)(y))\\
=&(\delta-(a+b).1)^{n-1}((\delta-a.1)(x)y)+(\delta-(a+b).1)^{n-1}(x(\delta-b.1)y)\\
=&\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose i}(\delta-a.1)^{n-i-1}((\delta-a.1)(x))(\delta-b.1)^i(y)\\
&+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose i}(\delta-a.1)^{n-i-1}(x)(\delta-b.1)^i((\delta-b.1)(y))\\
=&\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose i}(\delta-a.1)^{n-i}(x)(\delta-b.1)^i(y)\\
&+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose i}(\delta-a.1)^{n-i-1}(x)(\delta-b.1)^{i+1}(y)\\
=&\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose i}(\delta-a.1)^{n-i}(x)(\delta-b.1)^i(y)\\
&+\sum_{i=1}^{n}{n-1\choose i-1}(\delta-a.1)^{n-i}(x)(\delta-b.1)^{i}(y)\\
=&(\delta-a.1)^{n}(x)y+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left[{n-1\choose i}+{n-1\choose i-1}\right](\delta-a.1)^{n-i}(x)(\delta-b.1)^i(y)\\
&+x(\delta-b.1)^n(y).
\end{align}
Now use the identity
$$
{n-1\choose i}+{n-1\choose i-1}={n\choose i}.
$$